# Never ending service that hears to incoming data though a port from some IP address for UDP data

Tags: android

I am building an application that connects with a server which is my Raspberry pi.
    My android application sends data to the server and gets the response for the sent command.
    Raspberry pi can generate interrupts at any time and will send it to the android application. I want to create a service that should never die and should always keep on listening to the interrupts sent by raspberry pie.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * This is a service that will never stop and will again restart if it gets killed
 */
public class WifiUnstoppableService extends Service{

    private static final String TAG = WifiUnstoppableService.class.getSimpleName();
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    private String result = null;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 2 * 2000);
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    try {

                        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
                        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.42.1", 5001);
                        socket.bind(address);

                        try {
                            byte[] receiveData = new byte[2048];
                            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

                            socket.receive(receivePacket);
                            String receivedPacket = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                            Log.d(TAG, receivedPacket);
                            socket.close();

                        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }catch (SocketException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }




    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    };




    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        try {
            mTimer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.test.interruptReceiver");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}

But this is not working.
Can anyone help me with what am I doing wrong.
```

Comment: Can you specify your problem? And state the question clear?

Answer (score 0):

Practically you should not create a never ending service because if you create one, it will not work properly due to doze mode. And more thing, in Android O you are strictly not allowed to run a service for a unlimited time in background.